# Grouping data with pandas into separate batches

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function which adds a column onto a `DataFrame` that creates a batch number for a set of time data. I am assuming that once the level goes below/above 1000 we have emptied (and then refilled) the batch and thus it's a new batch. This means I can then group the data by batch number to do further analysis.

My data looks like

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(
{ 'Time'  : [1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800],
  'Level' : [ 200, 1300, 1500,  200, 1500, 1400],
  'Data'  : range(6) })

   Data  Level  Time
0     0    200  1300
1     1   1300  1400
2     2   1500  1500
3     3    200  1600
4     4   1500  1700
5     5   1400  1800
```

And what I want it to look like is:

```
   Batch  Data  Level  Time
0    NaN     0    200  1300
1      1     1   1300  1400
2      1     2   1500  1500
3    NaN     3    200  1600
4      2     4   1500  1700
5      2     5   1400  1800
```

I'm not bothered about what happens to the batch number between batches. NaN seems like a sensible choice but anything separate and distinct.

So far I've tried doing:

```
df['inUse'] = df['Level'] > 1000
```

And then trying to work out how to number a column and start a new number every true but can't work out how. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

### EDIT

Tried:

```
df['Batch'] = (df['Level'] < 1000).cumsum()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\alarr\Python\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1662, in cumsum
    np.putmask(result, mask, pa.NA)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Also using python 2.7.5 and pandas 0.12.0. Also worth mentioning I would like to apply this to datasets of up to 1 million rows. Forgot to mention this!

### Solved:

I tried both answers on my main dataset and both worked! Thank you. Out of curiosity, I timed both and cumsum method ran in 0.016s whereas counter ran in 0.156s. Interesting to see the difference between both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work with pandas version 0.13 or better:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time'  : [1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800],
                    'Level' : [ 200, 1300, 1500,  200, 1500, 1400],
                    'Data'  : range(6) })
df['Batch'] = (df['Level'] < 1000).cumsum()
print(df)
```

yields

```
   Data  Level  Time  Batch
0     0    200  1300      1
1     1   1300  1400      1
2     2   1500  1500      1
3     3    200  1600      2
4     4   1500  1700      2
5     5   1400  1800      2
```

If you'd like a `NaN` between batches, then you could do this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time'  : [1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800],
                    'Level' : [ 200, 1300, 1500,  200, 1500, 1400],
                    'Data'  : range(6) })

mask = df['Level'] < 1000
df['Batch'] = mask.cumsum()
df.ix[mask, 'Batch'] = np.nan
print(df)
```

which yields

```
   Data  Level  Time  Batch
0     0    200  1300    NaN
1     1   1300  1400      1
2     2   1500  1500      1
3     3    200  1600    NaN
4     4   1500  1700      2
5     5   1400  1800      2
```

---

Edit: **For Pandas version 0.12 or older**, [there was an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4170) related to using `cumsum` on boolean Series. This might be the source of the error you are seeing. In that case, try converting the mask to dtype `int` before applying `cumsum`:

```
mask = (df['Level'] < 1000)
df['Batch'] = mask.astype('int').cumsum()
df.ix[mask, 'Batch'] = np.nan
```

Comment: I've just tried this and got:

    np.putmask(result, mask, pa.NA)
    ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: The full traceback was actually useful. Please post it again. Maybe in your original post where it can be formatted better.

Comment: Editted my question to include full traceback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you're happy to use a global variable, you could to something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time'  : [1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800],
                    'Level' : [ 200, 1300, 1500,  200, 1500, 1400],
                    'Data'  : range(6) })
counter = 0
def handler(x):
    global counter
    if x>1000: return counter
    counter += 1
    return float('nan')

df['Batch'] = df.Level.apply(handler)
print df
```